# SQL Query Group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've got table with column called BODY. In this column you can find texts where there is a number somewhere ( you don't know the position where number occurs). Text might be the same in few rows but number differs. I want to group same texts but ommit numbers which differs. For the following data below I should have 2 groups counted 3 elements each. How to group by something like that?

```
'here is some text 888697885 more text in row'
'here is some text 234234234 more text in row'
'here is some text 345345345 more text in row'

'here 234234234 is some different text in row'
'here 234234456 is some different text in row'
'here 554645645 is some different text in row'
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: If the number is repeating in some group should it be counted?

Comment: Yes. I think the answer you've uploaded 5 minutes ago was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(REPLACE(details, LEFT(SUBSTRING(details, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', details), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(details, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', details), 8000) + 'X') -1) ,''))
FROM supportContacts
GROUP BY REPLACE(details, LEFT(SUBSTRING(details, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', details), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(details, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', details), 8000) + 'X') -1) ,'');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f9fa/13)

Just replace your column and table names.